# AWK Printing Lines and discarding some of them

Tags: awk

I am an AWK newbie. I have a following motif in a huge file.

```
~ Gradients ~
~   x               y            z      ~
~~ 
~ H         1      0.00781      0.00108      0.00038 ~
~ H         2      0.01271     -0.01507      0.02839 ~
~ C         1     -0.05015     -0.01803      0.01588 ~
~ O         1      0.01733      0.03089     -0.04611 ~
~ O         2      0.01230      0.00114      0.00147 ~
```

I need to extract these numbers (x y z):

```
0.00781      0.00108      0.00038
0.01271     -0.01507      0.02839
-0.05015     -0.01803      0.01588
0.01733      0.03089     -0.04611 
0.01230      0.00114      0.00147
```

I wrote the following script:

```
awk '/z ~/ {for(i=-2; i<=3; i++) {getline; print $4, $5, $6}}' filename
```

But it gives me blank line due to "~~" line.

I would like to ignore this line and only gets the xyz columns

```
xyz
xyz
xyz
xyz
```

etc. without any blank lines...

Could anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain more clearly ***exactly*** what you are trying to do? 
It looks like you are trying to print x, y, and z values
(`$4`, `$5`, and `$6`) from the next six lines
after a line that contains a literal `z` followed by a `~`. 
But that doesn’t make much sense — unless you have a repeating pattern
of a header, five lines of data, another header, another five lines of data,
etc. — and, if that’s the case, you really need to explain that. 
And if that is what you are trying to do, why are you doing it
with `for(i=-2; i<=3; i++)` instead of `for(i=1; i<=6; i++)`.

And that’s not a good way to use `getline`.

If I correctly understand your objective, all you need is

```
awk 'NF==7 {print $4, $5, $6}' filename
```

That will print the 4th, 5th, and 6th fields (x, y, and z)
from every line that has seven fields, and ignore everything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. Well, what I am trying to do is to ask two quantum chemistry programs to talk to each other. So in principle, I am continuously producing the above quoted, repeating motive starting with ~Gradient~ and trying to print x, y, and z values ($4, $5, and $6) from the next six lines after a line that contains a literal z followed by a ~.

Comment: In other words, each time when I find the 'z ~' iteral, I want to skip another line (iteral + 1) and only print the content from five another lines (iteral+2 +3 +4 +5 +6). And of course It needs to be a repeating operation (doing it on and on hundreds thousand of times). I apologize for not being exact...

Comment: Ah, I see now that you used the word “motif” to mean “a repeating pattern.”  I didn’t understand that when I read it, and I suspect that few people would. As I said, that sort of thing should be more clearly explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing
because your data appear to have a header line ending with `z      ~`
and your command appears to search for `/z ~/`, so they should not match. 
But maybe it’s actually `zTab~` in both places.

For simplicity, I’ll use `/z *~/`, to match a `z`,
followed by any number of spaces, followed by a `~`. 
Go ahead and keep on using whatever search string works for you.

You have clarified in a comment that you want
to print the x, y, and z values from the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th lines
after a header line that contains the `z   ~`. 
Here’s a way to do that in `awk`:

```
awk '
        /z *~/          { counter=1; next }
        counter > 1     { print $4, $5, $6 }
        counter == 6    { counter = 0 }
        counter > 0     { counter++ }
    ' filename
```

- `/z *~/    { counter=1; next }` says,
  when we see a line that contains the `z   ~`, we set a counter to 1. 
  This will be used to count the next six lines. 
  Use the `next` command to do no further processing on this line —
  we don’t want to even consider the possibility of printing the header line.
- `counter > 1 { print $4, $5, $6 }` prints x, y, and z from lines
  where `counter > 1`. 
  Note that this is not testing `counter > 0` or `counter >= 1`,
  so it skips the 1st line after the header,
  and prints the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th, and 6th lines.
- `counter == 6  { counter = 0 }` says, when `counter` reaches 6,
  we’re done with this “motif”, so we set `counter` to zero.
- `counter > 0   { counter++ }` simply says that,
  as long as we’re in a “motif”,
  we should increment (add one to) the `counter` for each line.